# CMake : different configure_file() for each target

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I'm not very familiar with `cmake` but as the title says what i'd like to do is the following:

I've an header file of configuration (eg `config.h.in`), in which I'd like to specify all my parameters depending on which target I'm currently calling. So my header file is something like:

```
#cmakedefine TEST @TEST@
#cmakedefine PINK @PINK@

#ifndef TEST
#define MY_A 10    
#endif
#ifdef PINK
#define MY_A 20
#endif
```

Now, in my `CMakeLists.txt` I would like to have multiple targets, so for example (actually the `config.h`file is just included from other `.c` files)

```
add_executable(FirstTarget
    something.c
    somethingelse.c
    config.h
)

add_executable(SecondTarget
    something.c
    somethingother.c
    config.h
)
```

And what i would really like to do is that `FirstTarget` And `SecondTarget` have different configuration file, so what I'm asking is if it possible to run something like

```
set(TEST Test)
configure_file(config.h.in config.h)
```

just for target `FirstTarget`, and then someway running for `SecondTarget`

```
set(PINK Test2)
configure_file(config.h.in config.h)
```

so that if i call `make FirstTarget` and `make SecondTarget` they've different configuration parameters each.

Thanks!

Comment: With `configure_file` you may create as many files as you want, just make sure that every time you are specifying a different target file. Each target file will be created with the variables set at corresponded `configure_file` call. So, what do you want from us? If you do not like to have many `config.h` files, then you need to make single `config.h` to differentiate targets. E.g. with `#ifdef` (assuming you would use [target_compile_definition](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_compile_definitions.html) for specify compile definitions for your targets).

Comment: @Tsyvarev i don't wanna have many `config.h` files. But I'm reading doc about `target_compile_definition` i and may be exactly what i was looking for: all I have to do i specify (for example) `target_compile_definitions(First PRIVATE PINK)` and then check with `#ifdef` in the `config.h.ih` if the constant is defined?

Comment: Yes, in the `config.h.in` you may check with `#ifdef` whether a private compile definition is defined or not.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If you put that as an answer i will accept it, otherwise the question may be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `configure_file` creates a "real" file: it has the **same content** for each target.

However, the created file may contain `#ifdef` (or other conditional statements), so its *interpretation* may *differ* for different target.

Following example uses [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_compile_definitions.html) command for "assign" compile definitions for a specific target.

**config.h**:

```
#ifndef TEST
#define MY_A 10    
#endif
#ifdef PINK
#define MY_A 20
#endif
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(FirstTarget ...)
# When "config.h" will be included into this target, it will use "PINK" branch.
target_compile_definitions(FirstTarget PRIVATE PINK)

add_executable(SecondTarget ...)
# When "config.h" will be included into this target, it will use "TEST" branch.
target_compile_definitions(FirstTarget PRIVATE TEST)
```